# Still no OPTGROUP?

Tags: combobox, dojo, optgroup

I read in the dojo trac from 3 years ago a concern that dojo combobox needs to implement option groups. I am using version 1.3.2 and my combo is failing. Are the option groups still not supported after all this time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a way to use optgroups in the combobox widget. That ticket was closed and no new one was ever opened. There is also not really a way the data could be represented consistently in dojo.data either. It would be possible to create a custom solution to this by editing the dijit though, just manage the optgroups in the way that makes sense for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `dijit-select-optgroup` if you are willing to use a Select alike widget.

`dijit-select-optgroup` is basically a custom version of `dijit/form/Select` which includes grouping of options (similar to html `<select>` element with `<optgroup>`).

More info:
https://github.com/gibbok/dijit-select-optgroup

Live demo:
https://gibbok.github.io/dijit-select-optgroup

Disclaim: I own this repo :).